# Can I configure tiles 3.0 with Spring 3.1.1

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles-3

Can I configure tiles 3.0 version with Spring 3.1.1 version .

I was using 3.1.1 version of spring with tile  2.0 . I want to change tiles 2.0 to tiles 3.0. When I am implementing this I am getting the class not found exception given below

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer

Is it possible to configure tiles 3.o with spring 3.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to spring-3.2 it's all easy as it provides tiles-3 integration for you.

see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.2.html

( ref: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8825 )

If you can't upgrade to spring-3.2 you can download just the new spring-tiles-3 integration classes from the above jira issue and integrate as described in http://tech.finn.no/2012/07/25/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/2/